# Sinatra Gem Won't Install

Tags: ruby, nginx, rubygems, sinatra, passenger

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on a linode trying to get sinatra, passenger, nginx, and rvm to all play nice with Ruby 1.9.2. I'm running into an issue with gems though:

~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems$ ls returns

```
daemon_controller-0.2.6  fastthread-1.0.7  passenger-3.0.9  rack-1.3.2  rake-0.9.2
```

and gem list 
returns

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rack (1.3.2)
rake (0.9.2)
sinatra (1.2.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
```

What is odd to me is that they aren't the same. And sinatra is missing from the .rvm gems.

When I go to my website I get the following:

```
Error message:
no such file to load -- sinatra
```

with `/home/noahc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb on line 36 in`require'`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem with your rvm gemset not beeing used.

First, `cd /yourprojectdir` and create a `.rvmrc` and matching gemset for your project

```
rvm --rvmrc --create 1.9.2@yourprojectname
```

Then make sure you are using the gemset

```
rvm gemset list
```

The arrow should point to your gemset, if it's not do `rvm gemset use yourprojectname`.

Now install your gems with `gem install`, or - better - `bundle install`.

Passenger 3 should detect your `.rvmrc` and use the correct gemset automatically.

Comment: Is there a way I can confirm I did this correctly? I didn't get any errors or anything, but it still is not working. You can see exactly what I see at http://shiftfrog.com if you want the whole stack trace.

Comment: Your webserver is spawning the wrong Passenger gem. In `.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/` you can see it isn't using any gemset at all. I can't tell more without knowing a bit about your webserver configuration. Which webserver are your using? And how was Passenger installed?

Comment: I'm using nginx. I used the following process to install it: http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-10-with-rvm-passenger-and-nginx/

Comment: Can you explain how you know that the web server is spawning the wrong Passenger gem?

Comment: If correctly loaded, the gempath of your Passenger would look like `.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@yourgemsetwouldbehere/gems/passenger-3.0.9/`.

Comment: According to the guide you let the Passenger gem install Nginx for you. The Passenger module gets compiled into Nginx, thats why the wrong one still gets loaded. Delete the `/opt/nginx` directory, make sure you are in the correct gemset by `rvm gemset list` and run `passenger-install-nginx-module` again. It will build Nginx again, with the right gem. You don't need the `passenger_ruby` line anymore that is mentioned in the guide, Passenger 3 will find and use your rvmrc automatically.