# Make Nginx use the correct passenger gem

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger, rvm

I am trying to setup an nginx + sinatra + ubuntu 10.04 + passenger + rvm stack. I followed the directions here: http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-10-with-rvm-passenger-and-nginx/

This is a follow up to this post: [Sinatra Gem Won't Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310050/sinatra-gem-wont-install). I also followed the directions given by another stack overflow that essential creates an .rvmrc in my app and I've added the passenger gem.

According to the previous post, I am spawning the wrong passenger.

In my nginx conf file I'm using: `passenger_root /home/noahc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9;`

How do I find out which passenger I'm supposed to be spawning and how do I change it?

You can visit http://shiftfrog and see the stacktrace that generated this question and the previous one.

Any ideas? Am I doing this in the wrong order?

Should I setup RVM, then ruby, then follow the directions for setting up the gemset and rvmrc file in my project directory. Then run the rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module command from the gemset I created. Currently I ran it outside of the gemset I created according to the previous stackoverflow question I reference earlier.

Thank in advance for any help you could lend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite nice description on RVM site and Dercys blog:

- https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/
- http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration